# Statement about polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

We know that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial on the real numbers, $|p(x)| \rightarrow \infty $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.
From this, is it correct if I say that

For any $\epsilon > 0, \exists M > 0$ such that $x \geq M$ implies $|p(x)|\geq \epsilon$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork A non-eventually-monotonic polynomial?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of $p(x)\to\infty$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: You need non-constant polynomials.

Comment: Under the restriction of Kavi Rama Murthy's comment, which amounts to saying that the degree of the polynomial must be greater than zero, your work is valid.

Comment: Yes this is valid. Though I would say that it is uncommon to use $\epsilon$ to represent big numbers, it would be more common to say that for any $M > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $x > N$ implies $|p(x)| > M$.